# Selenium - codeception - chrome issue

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I get the following errors in random when running test on chrome using codeception in selenium server:

```
WebDriver\Exception\UnknownError: The current platform is not supported: LINUX

WebDriver\Exception\UnknownError: Unable to find executable for product Opera Desktop

WebDriver\Exception\UnknownError: The path to the driver executable must be set by the phantomjs.binary.path capability/system property/PATH variable; for more information, see https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki. The latest version can be downloaded from http:\//phantomjs.org/download.html
```

When given firefox, it works fine.

command for running selenium:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar -browser googlechrome
```

Following is the `acceptance.yml` content

```
class_name: WebGuy
modules:
  enabled:
    - Selenium2
    - WebHelper
  config:
    Selenium2:
      url: 'http://www.google.com'
      browser: googlechrome
  delay: 350
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To run codeception with Chrome, use the following `acceptance.suite.yml`:

```
class_name: WebGuy
modules:
  enabled:
    - Selenium2
    - WebHelper
  config:
    Selenium2:
      url: 'http://www.google.com'
      browser: chrome
      delay: 350
```

Note that i changed your browser in the config from `googlechrome` to `chrome`.

Also, start Selenium2 by using this command:

`java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=./chromedriver -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar`

Note that you don't need to specify the browser when starting selenium.

You can download chromedriver [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list). You should also update your selenium standalone server; you can get the latest version from [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list).